# Issue with CMake setup in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

love to get some help regarding an issue with the Cmake extension in VScode that im hoping someone has experienced before, I'm driving myself mad on this small error. I am completely new with VScode so please let me know if you need more infomation, anyway the error when i try to build is;

Bad CMake executable “”. Is it installed or settings contain the correct path (cmake.cmakePath)?

I am using windows and have tried adding the Cmake location to my path, even tried on another laptop but nothing is working. Any help would be amazing.

Cheers.

Comment: File->Preferences->Settings->Extensions->CMake Tools configuration ->CMake: CMake path?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fabian, I changed the cmake path to the executable path where vscode is installed in my computer (C:\Microsoft VS Code), however it still comes up with the same error just with the vscode location in the quotation marks. If you could give me a few other pointer i would really appreciate it, cheers.

Comment: @Sam_Zinger did you solve this issue? As in with the new path now in quotation marks? Thanks